# GCP Spanner Template ReadWrite Transaction Not Working

Tags: java, google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-spanner

I want to perform units of work in a single transaction using Google spanner template,

```
spannerTemplate.performReadWriteTransaction(trasac -> {
  // Write in table 1
  // Write in table 2   
});
```

Am getting exception as 'Nested transactions are not supported', please help me on this.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe this could help: I had @Transactional annotations on service methods that called *performReadWriteTransaction* method, so I removed that annotation. As stated [here](https://cloud.spring.io/spring-cloud-gcp/1.1.x/multi/multi__spring_data_cloud_spanner.html#_declarative_transactions_with_transactional_annotation) such methods "cannot be used in @Transactional annotated methods because Cloud Spanner does not support transactions within transactions."

Answer (score 0):

As per the change described [here](https://github.com/googleapis/google-cloud-java/pull/3628) nested transactions are blocked by default on Spanner Client libraries.

To override this behavior you can call  `TransactionRunner.allowNestedTransaction()` instead.

Comment: can you please share me the link

Comment: sure, the link is: https://github.com/googleapis/google-cloud-java/pull/3628